# View only files without extension in File choose Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, file-chooser

In Windows 7, When i open a file choose dialog from notepad++ or notepad or wordpad or from some other editor software, how can i filter files to view only files without any extension?

I know that we can search for files without extension by "ext:[]". But how can be do the same from file choose dialog? I hope there must some string like ext:[]. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem with entering exactly what you mention 'ext:[]' in the Search box?

Comment: @snowdude Not working. All the files are listed. No filtering happens

Comment: Ah, all I can say is that it works for me on Win 7 (if I pick a specific folder).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. My best guesses would be `*.` or maybe just `*` but those display no files, and all files, respectively. Since those don't work, it's likely that there is no pattern that will match exactly files without an extension.

I think the second best option would be to sort by type, which would at least put the file without extension in a consecutive group, as type `File`.